# Distinguish models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models:

```
Applications, Permission, User
```

And for Application I have

```
has_many :permissions, :through => app_default
has_many :permissions, :through => app_perm
```

Will that work? If I do Application.permission from which table will take the permissions? What about nested forms as well?

Comment: No, it won't work, the last is going to override the first.

Answer (score 0):

Use polymorhpic associations to get this work.

Comment: How can you achieve that using polymorphic?